# Can you install Ubuntu from the hard disk?

Tags: installation, disk

Is it possible to install Ubuntu from the hard disk?

Comment: How do you mean? From a hard disk instead of a CD or USB?

Comment: Interesting question. I would like to download the .iso into a free partition and install then ubuntu into the wanted partition

Comment: @BernardDecock https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Answer (score 6):

Yes.
Ubuntu can be installed from hard disk without using any secondary media like CD or USB.

You can read the full tutorial here.

http://agnipulse.com/2011/08/install-ubuntu-hard-disk/

Grub4Dos bootloader is used to boot from the Ubuntu iso on the hard disk.After booting, the isodevice is unmounted by running some commands in the terminal.Then you can install Ubuntu the normal way.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way for Windows Vista / 7 users. Download the Ubuntu iso file you want to install, and use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1). Open EasyBCD and click "Add New Entry" from the left side. Then on the bottom, select "ISO Boot" and then find the ISO file you want to boot from. Then give it a name, click "Add Entry," and then Restart. There should be an option (when you boot) to boot from the entry you just made.

Comment: I tried this and got the infamous "unable to find a medium containing a live file system" message. The only solutions I found online were talking about changing to USB2.0 plug. Did this happen to you too?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [Ubuntu help page on installing Ubuntu from another Linux partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux). Essentially you just get the installer's .iso image, extract it onto a new partition, then boot from it to start the installer. EDIT: This method gave me installer errors about partitioning because I had a USB drive plugged in that I wasn't using. I didn't want to use the USB drive for the installer because I didn't want to delete its existing contents. After removing the USB drive this method worked fine.

If you don't have another Linux partition, here is an [Ubuntu help page on other ways to install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I installed Ubuntu on 2 computers via Wubi and almost no problems. The only problem is that it doesn't detect the other partitions from Ubuntu because of the way it is installed(in a file allocated on the hard drive) which is pretty bad...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Wubi

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this route. Horrible and causes nothing but problems.

Comment: It's not that bad for beginners.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.