# Instead of using an installation USB to install Ubuntu onto a diff USB drive, can I use Ubuntu installed on my computer the and just use 1 USB?

Tags: usb

I want an actual installation on my 1 USB, not a live USB with persistent storage. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You've not provided any product/release specifics, as Ubuntu is available in more than one product, with different ISOs & installer(s) found on those ISOs.  With some of them installing to a different thumb-drive is easy, with others it's more complex; though hardware/firmware can also play a part (ie. one product/release on one make/model machine is easy, but same Ubuntu product/release on different make/model won't be easy due to *firmware* differences).  Yes it's possible for some Ubuntu products & on some hardware.

Comment: You can also (*I'm unsure if you're asking this*) make your installed systems boot loader offer to boot an ISO installed on partition; so only a single-USB-drive (where the installed system will go to) is required.. but that's a lot more work than just using two-thumb-drives; and how to do this varies on your machine/firmware/OS-installed etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you install Ubuntu from the hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25668/can-you-install-ubuntu-from-the-hard-disk)

Comment: @karel: The OP is asking how to do a Full install to USB, not a live USB with persistent storage. Your link is mostly about Wubi, nothing about Full install to USB.

Comment: **create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-22-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step** https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403792/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-22-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Your way is correct as both of us know, but I put my link here for the OP to read because the OP doesn't want to use a 2nd USB as installation media.

Comment: Can Ubuntu be installed to the pendrive it was booted from?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from or If you are running Ubuntu on your hard drive: 20.04 booting .iso from GRUB menu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Ubuntu be installed to the pendrive it was booted from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from)